# running mean of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

Given the nxN matrix A. I want to find the running mean of the rows of the matrix. For this I have done:

```
mean = cumsum(A, 2);
for k = 1:N
    mean(:, k) = mean(:, k)/k;
end
```

but for large N this takes a while. Is there a more efficient way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: `mean` is already a function, be careful when naming a variable the same way as a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** zeeMonkeez's solution is fastest according to some rough benchmarks at the end of my post.

How about

```
N = 1000;
A = rand(N, N);
m = cumsum(A, 2);
m1 = zeros(size(m));
tic
for j = 1:1000;
    for k = 1:N
        m1(:, k) = m(:, k)/k;
    end
end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 6.971112 seconds.

```
tic
for j = 1:1000
n = repmat(1:N, N, 1);
m2 = m./n;
end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 2.471035 seconds.

Here, you transform your problem into a matrix multiplication (instead of dividing element-wise, divide one matrix by the other point-wise). The matrix you would like to divide by looks like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, ..., N;
 1, 2, .....
 .
 .
 1, 2, ....     ]
```

which you can get using [repmat](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

**EDIT: BENCHMARK**

bsxfun as used by @zeeMonkeez is even faster. Both, for the above case (10% difference on my system) and also for a larger matrix (N = 10000) for which case my version actually performs worst (35 sec, vs 30 from OP and 23 from zeeMonkeez's solution).

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, [`bsxfun`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) is even faster:

```
N = 1000;
A = rand(N, N);
m = cumsum(A, 2);

tic
for j = 1:1000;
    m2 = bsxfun(@rdivide, m, 1:N);
end
toc
```

Elapsed time: 1.555507 seconds.

`bsxfun` avoids having to allocate memory for the divisor as `repmat` does.